# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException when using the same object from singleton

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I write server based on Springboot.I have `MonsterFactory` in which I have `MonsterType` objects, where MonsterType is entity.

```
public class MonsterFactory {

    public static final MonsterFactory INSTANCE = new MonsterFactory();
    private Map<String,MonsterType> monsterTypesMap = new HashMap<>();

    private MonsterFactory(){
        monsterTypesMap.put("Fire Golem", new MonsterType("Fire Golem","Opis",
            new MonsterStats(100,40,30,10),"/jakis/path"));
        monsterTypesMap.put("Bat", new MonsterType("Bat", "Opis 2",
            new MonsterStats(50,20,30,40),"/jakis/path2"));
    }

    public Monster create(final String name, Location location){
        MonsterType monsterType = monsterTypesMap.get(name);
        if(monsterType == null)
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("unknown monster type");
        return new Monster(monsterType,location);
   }
}
```

Now when I want to add some Monster objects to my `MonsterRepostory monsters` like this:

```
monsters.save(MonsterFactory.create("Fire Golem", new Location(40,80));
monsters.save(MonsterFactory.create("Fire Golem", new Location(50, 80));
```

I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`.

Is it problem that I use the same instance of `MonsterType` object for creating two different monsters or what? I'm new in Spring and Hibernate and don't know where the problem comes from.

EDIT:
okay, I found that I get nested exception: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist`

Comment: Oups, my bad, there should be `MonsterFactory.INSTANCE.create(...)`

Comment: So how does this code relate to Spring?

Comment: My bad, there should be JPA, sorry. The problem is `MonsterType` is Entity and when I run springboot I get this exception. It looks like I couldn't use the same isntance of `MonsterType` object twice to add two monsters of the same `MonsterType` but different `Location`